# ¿Cómo ejecuto plugins externos?

Tags: html

Intento cargar una pagina en un `<iframe>`, pero al cargarla **funciona bien en firefox** con formularios y todo al ingresar en la sección pague sin registrar.

Pero al momento de ingresar **en chrome no carga** siendo que la pagina, funciona bien en chrome. El problema es que ellos crearon los plugins de formulario, pero no me cargan al momento de iframe. Intenté con *AJAX* y javascript nativo pero daba problema de cors, intenté con *PHP* el mismo problema.

```
<iframe src="https://villalemana.vecinodigital.cl" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

CORS es una política de compartimiento de archivos entre distintos orígenes, esta bloqueará las peticiones que no tenga en "la lista blanca", para averiguar si estamos autorizados a hacer una petición desde un dominio a hasta un dominio b, el navegador hace una petición primero de tipo `OPTIONS` de manera si el origen no está en la lista de orígenes admitidos del destino, la petición será bloqueada

Si intentas con AJAX, el servidor bloqueará le petición si no responde con los ecabezados necesarios:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  "https://origen.com"
```

- CORS Diferencia entre *HTTP* y *HTTPS*
- CORS Considera a subdominios dos dominios diferentes (sub.a.com !== a.com)

```
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Además, con un `<iframe>`, puede que *Firefox* haga un *bypass* a las políticas de compartimiento en los `<iframe>`, cosa que *Chrome* no pasa por alto

Como mencionamos antes, si el servidor no responde con los encabezados correctos, el `<iframe>` también será bloqueado

```html
<iframe src="https://es.stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
```

Pero, ya que usas PHP, puedes simplemente hacer un `file_get_contents`

```php
print file_get_contents("url");
```

Obtendremos el HTML completo de la página, si hay PHP en dicha página no se podrá obtener, como entenderás, por motivos de seguridad